# EAAccessory, iOS, Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, obd-ii, dongle, eaaccessory

I'm having a problem to send commands to my external accessory.
According to the manufacturer the command 'N', returns the hardware info.
But nothing in return .
PS : i'm using Apple sample code for EAAccessory.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of accessory is it? EAAccessory is for specific external accessories with support built-in into iOS, connected over the 30-pin or Lightning port or via Bluetooth Classic. It's not applicable to Bluetooth Low Energy (aka Smart Bluetooth, BLE...).

Comment: it's legacy Bluetooth that supports iOS, it's a dongle that is connected to an obd2 (on board diagnostics for cars) to collect information about your car. I could connect to it and retrieve all its informations but when trying to send commands, nothing happens...
PS : it's connected through a J1962 port

Comment: Without more details about the specific device, whether you use the manufacturer's SDK, what specific code actually works and what specific code actually doesn't, it's going to be difficult for anyone to help you much.

Comment: For example if i issue the "N" command , it sould return the hardware info, the "O" command is for opening a channel communication.
If the issued command is correct then the dongle should return this response "0x0D", else it sould return "0x07"...

Comment: If you are using legacy Bluetooth, it should be the SPP; does the MFi chip installed? or will you have a try with Android phone.

Comment: Yes , it's SPP, and the MFi chip is installed. By the way, the app is already developed on Android